# List subfolders in sidebar navigation

Tags: vue.js, vuepress

In my `config.js` file I have created this sidebar

```
    sidebar: {
        '/docs/': [
            '',
            'gettingStarted',
            'guides',
            'media'
        ],
        '/docs/gettingStarted/': [
            'creatingFirstApplication',
            'installing',
            'understanding'
        ],
        '/docs/gettingStarted/creatingFirstApplication': [
            'setup'
        ],
        '/docs/gettingStarted/installing': [
            'installation'
        ],
        '/docs/gettingStarted/understanding': [
            'why',
            'useCases',
            'coreConcepts',
            'architecture',
            'gettingHelp'
        ],
        '/docs/guides/': [
            'firstApplication'
        ],
        '/docs/media/': [
            'downloads',
            'onlineResources'
        ],
        '/docs/media/downloads': [
            'brochure'
        ],
        '/docs/media/onlineResources': [
            'articles',
            'videos'
        ]
    }
```

but I am only able to see the top level markdown files when building the page. So here you can see my project structure

[image]

When building the page only `README.md`, `gettingStarted.md`, `guides.md`, and `media.md` get rendered.

How can I fix it?

Please let me know if you need more information!

---

So this is the current state

[image]

and this is an example showing what I would like to achieve

[image]

---

I found more information here

https://vuepress.vuejs.org/theme/default-theme-config.html#multiple-sidebars

I tried to reverse my configuration

```
    sidebar: {
        '/docs/gettingStarted/creatingFirstApplication': [
            'setup'
        ],
        '/docs/gettingStarted/installing': [
            'installation'
        ],
        '/docs/gettingStarted/understanding': [
            'why',
            'useCases',
            'coreConcepts',
            'architecture',
            'gettingHelp'
        ],
        '/docs/gettingStarted/': [
            'creatingFirstApplication',
            'installing',
            'understanding'
        ],
        '/docs/guides/': [
            'firstApplication'
        ],
        '/docs/media/downloads': [
            'brochure'
        ],
        '/docs/media/onlineResources': [
            'articles',
            'videos'
        ],
        '/docs/media/': [
            'downloads',
            'onlineResources'
        ],
        '/docs/': [
            '',
            'gettingStarted',
            'guides',
            'media'
        ]
    }
```

but this didn't help.

---

I created a small repository providing a small documentation with two pages per directory.

https://github.com/Garzec/VuePressTest

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's... a little confusing but from what I understand you need subfolders...

Remember that VuePress sidebar is used to organize how the user *sees* the items in a specific order. The sources not matters name or where the .md file is. You can add from any path but is better to follow the [Directory structure convention](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/directory-structure.html#directory-structure).

---

There are some considerations in your case.

**Firstly...**

For subfolders routes, you need to create a `README.md` (take it like an `index.html`). So, you need a [Default Page Routing](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/directory-structure.html#default-page-routing). Router expects that the ending `/{page}/` has a `/{page}/README.md`

Try renaming your index pages to its subfolder like '{name}/README.md'.

For example `media.md` --> `media/README.md`.

**Secondly...**

There are some tree errors in your config.

I noticed you use `sidebar: {}` (as an object). This is intended to make [multiple sidebars](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/theme/default-theme-config.html#multiple-sidebars) (different pages/sections), like in VuePress documentation `Guide | Config Reference | Plugin |etc` you see in its navbar. If this is your goal, you have to place all child items inside '/docs/' for example and create a fallback:

```js
sidebar: {
    '/docs/': [
        '', // this is your docs/README.md
        // all sub-items here (I explain later)
    ],
    '/': [ // Your fallback (this is your landing page)
        '' // this is your README.md (main)
    ]       
}
```

**Thirdly...**

As I introduced before, you need to place all the items under that main.

Instead of creating a different route for each page, you can (after renaming I mentioned before) you need to remember that Sidebar (at least in the default theme) only have 1 route level. Their hierarchy levels are made by H2, h3, h4..., 
 not by file structure.

BUT... You can organize your sidebar sections by [grouping it](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/theme/default-theme-config.html#sidebar). For example:

```js
sidebar: {
  '/docs/': [
    '', // this is your docs/README.md

    {
      title: 'Getting Started',
      collapsable: false,
      children: [
        'gettingStarted/', // 'docs/gettingStarted/README.md' if you renamed before
        'gettingStarted/creatingFirstApplication',
        'gettingStarted/creatingFirstApplication/setup', // maybe better to move content to `creatingFirstApplication.md`
        'gettingStarted/installing/installation',

        // Maybe group all this in another another group if is much extense (instead of Getting Started)
        // or join into one file and use headers (to organize secions)
        'gettingStarted/understanding/why', 
        'gettingStarted/understanding/useCases',
        'gettingStarted/understanding/coreConcepts',
        'gettingStarted/understanding/architecture',
        'gettingStarted/understanding/gettingHelp',
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'Guides',
      collapsable: false,
      children: [
        'guides/', // 'docs/guides/README.md' if you renamed before
        'guides/firstApplication',              
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'Media',
      collapsable: false,
      children: [
        'media/', // 'docs/media/README.md' if you renamed before
        'media/downloads/brochure',
        'media/onlineResources/articles',
        'media/onlineResources/videos', 
      ]
    }
  ],

  '/': [ // Your fallback (this is your landing page)
    '' // this is your README.md (main)
  ]       
}
```

If you need split more, think in another section (instead of '/docs/' use each part as a new navbar item (like `Guide | Config Reference | Plugin |etc`)).

If not, you can also set the option `sidebarDepth` to `2`:

```js
themeConfig: {
  sidebar: {
    // . . . 
  },
  sidebarDepth: 2
}
```

---

I hope this helps you. :)

> Note: Maybe I missed some route, so check it your self.
>
> Note 2: Not run in local, but should be fine the structure/syntax. Again, check it and comment,

Comment: very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54019105/list-subfolders-in-sidebar-navigation#54071734) really helped us. We're running Vuepress 1.3.1 and ran into some issues using the [sidebar groups](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/theme/default-theme-config.html#sidebar-groups) example code above. (under thirdly)

We ended up with a fairly complex [sidebar](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/theme/default-theme-config.html#sidebar) and had to structure it accordingly. Below is an abbreviated version of our config file. ([whole config file](https://github.com/zumasys/docs/blob/master/site/.vuepress/config.js))

```
module.exports = {
   // Removed other config options for readability 
   themeConfig: {
      // Removed other themeConfig options for readability 
      sidebar: [
         "/",      
         {
            title: 'AccuTerm',
            path: '/accuterm/',
            collapsable: true,
            children: [
               {
                  title: 'Mobile',
                  path: '/accuterm/mobile/',
                  collapsable: true,
                  children: [
                     ['/accuterm/mobile/quick-start/', 'Quick Start'],
                     ['/accuterm/mobile/colors-and-themes-settings/', 'Colors & Themes Settings'],       
                     ['/accuterm/mobile/connection-settings/', 'Connection Settings'],
                     ['/accuterm/mobile/keyboard-and-clipboard-settings/', 'Keyboard & Clipboard Settings'],
                     ['/accuterm/mobile/screen-settings/', 'Screen Settings'],
                     ['/accuterm/mobile/terminal-settings/', 'Terminal Settings'],
                     ['/accuterm/mobile/user-guide/', 'User Guide']
                  ]
               },
               {
                  title: 'Web',
                  path: '/accuterm/web/',
                  collapsable: true,
                  children: [
                     ['/accuterm/web/web-introduction/', 'Web Introduction'],
                     ['/accuterm/web/getting-started/', 'Getting Started'],
                     ['/accuterm/web/release-notes/', 'Release Notes'],
                     ['/accuterm/web/activating-accuterm-desktop-licensing/', 'Activating AccuTerm Desktop Licensing'],
                     ['/accuterm/web/batch-user-actions/', 'Batch User Actions'],
                     ['/accuterm/web/change-password/', 'Change AccuTerm.IO Password'],
                     ['/accuterm/web/clipboard-settings/', 'Clipboard Settings'],
                     ['/accuterm/web/connection-settings/', 'Connection Settings'],
                     ['/accuterm/web/creating-profiles/', 'Creating Profiles'],
                     ['/accuterm/web/creating-roles/', 'Creating Roles'],
                     ['/accuterm/web/creating-users/', 'Creating Users'],
                     ['/accuterm/web/font-and-character-settings/', 'Font & Character Settings'],
                     ['/accuterm/web/installing-accuterm-io-server/', 'Installing AccuTerm IO Server'],
                     ['/accuterm/web/keyboard-options/', 'Keyboard Options'],
                     ['/accuterm/web/mouse-settings/', 'Mouse Settings'],
                     ['/accuterm/web/sound-settings/', 'Sound Settings'],
                     ['/accuterm/web/terminal-screen-options/', 'Terminal Screen Options'],
                     ['/accuterm/web/terminal-settings/', 'Terminal Settings'],
                     ['/accuterm/web/web-profiles/', 'Web Profiles'],
                     ['/accuterm/web/rezume-session-resilience/', 'AccuTerm ReZume Session Resilience'],
                     ['/accuterm/web/phi-reports/', 'PHI Reports']             
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         ["/docs/jbase/", "jBASE"]
      ]
   }
};
```

**Directory Structure**
[image: Docs Directory Structure]

Hopefully seeing this example will help clarify sidebar groups. To see the whole sidebar and directory structure view it on github:
[Vuepress config file](https://github.com/zumasys/docs/blob/master/site/.vuepress/config.js)
[Vuepress directory structure](https://github.com/zumasys/docs/tree/master/site)